# Eclipse Formatter - how to avoid blank lines and spaces?

Tags: eclipse, formatter, eclipse-formatter

Using the default Eclipse Formatter "Eclipse [build-in]" in one project, it adds unnecessary lines and blank spaces. I cannot explain this behaviour since I used this formatter for a vey long time and never saw this occurring.

This:

```
List<String> pp1 = Arrays.asList(p1, p6, p11);
List<String> pp2 = Arrays.asList(p2, p7, p12);
List<String> pp3 = Arrays.asList(p3, p8, p13);
List<String> pp4 = Arrays.asList(p4, p9, p14);
List<String> pp5 = Arrays.asList(p5, p10, p15);
```

becomes this:

```
List < String > pp1 = Arrays.asList(p1, p6, p11);

List < String > pp2 = Arrays.asList(p2, p7, p12);

List < String > pp3 = Arrays.asList(p3, p8, p13);

List < String > pp4 = Arrays.asList(p4, p9, p14);

List < String > pp5 = Arrays.asList(p5, p10, p15);
```

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
It was due to project specific settings which apparently overrides your local formatter.

If you encounter unexpected behaviour with Eclipse Formatter, it might be because of that.

[image]